# present a viewController over present controller as a popUp

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a UIView Controller and want to call this controller on a button click as a popup. I'm using KGModel to represent the popup on the screen.
 The code to call the controller and show with KGModel is

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoveToReviewView") as? ReviewViewController
controller?.assignValue = self

let ret = self.view.frame // view frame
controller.view.frame.size.width = ret.size.width - ret.size.width/4
controller.view.frame.size.height = ret.size.height/2

KGModal.sharedInstance().show(withContentView: controller.view, andAnimated: true)
```

This code is working and showing the view.

- The problem is when I'm presenting the view in KGModel then delegates of tableview is not getting called and cells are not showing.
- But when i call the controller as child view controller then it working fine.

I don't know what should be the issue that delegates are not getting called.

Comment: Where are you assigning the delegate?

Comment: it is assigned in the UI of UIViewController

Comment: Can you try using `showWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentViewController andAnimated:(BOOL)animated` so it present the viewcontroller instead of just the view? I don't know the framework but that could be worth a try.

Comment: please use "modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext". if the presented vc background is clear or dim, then you can show it like as popup.

Comment: @kevin thanks for the help its working now :)